# Почему ViewPager заполняет память?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

Активити содержит ViewPager. На каждой его странице лежит ImageView (картинка 450*675, 73кБ). Всего страниц 30 шт. Начинаю листать страницы. На 25 появляется ошибка: "Failed to allocate a 51916812 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 25MB until OOM". Я думал, что ViewPager загружает и выгружает картинки из памяти по мере необходимости. Но, оказывается, что не выгружает! Можно ли как-то заставить систему выгружать неиспользуемые в данный момент изображения? Я вставил в манифест строку android:largeHeap="true" и всё заработало, но это не решает проблему. А если картинок будет больше - снова зависнет? Может быть ViewPager2 не имеет такой проблемы? Подскажите

Comment: Попробуйте вручную очищать память неотображаемых страниц. Типа как-то так, например: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19882729/3212712

Comment: переписал код под ViewPager2 и поставил android:largeHeap="false" - не зависает. Но когда попробовал увеличить размер картинок до 800*1200 - на первой же странице заметный тормоз, а на 3-й вылет. Я только изучаю андроид. Не пойму, как в программах выводят на экран большие изображения, которые можно слайдить? Это какие-то специальные виджеты, или библиотеки?

Comment: Это довольно сложная задача. В двух словах описать не получится. Попробуйте вот по этой статье соорудить кэш для картинок: https://habr.com/ru/post/169883/ Ну а дальше всякие оптимизации по снижению качества картинок, их предзагрузки не в главном потоке и прочее. Возможно, вам стоит ещё библиотеку типа Glide использовать для отображения картинок